# Find all @Suppress annotation and //noinspection comment that the Lint tool of Android Studio generated before

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, suppress-warnings

I'm fixing warning and error issues that were reported by Lint tool of Android Studio. Some of them I don't want to fix now so I suppress them to ignore, using

```
//noinspection <name>
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("<name>")
```

However, Is there any proper way to find all of the issues that were suppressed to ignore (using above annotation and comment) by using Lint tool or Android Studio tool ? Now I only find the way to find all of "**@SuppressWarnings**" is using "Find Usage" and the way to find all of "**//noinspection**" is using the feature "Find in Path" of Android Studio. I think I need the another proper way to find. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

In android studio,

> You can find anything from whole project using  **ctrl+ shift+ f**

and

> if you want to replace than you can use **ctrl+shift+r**  key

Note; These both will work for full project.

If you want to find on perticular file then use **ctrl+f**

and for replase you can use **ctrl+r**

Comment: :( thanks for your answer however is there any way to find with another tool which can support me to know how many @SuppressWarnings("<name>") (For example @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")) used in the project ?

Comment: :) When you, ctrl+shift+f then a dialog box is opened. There you will get 2 options=> first is options and second is Preview. So just click on Preview, You will get a list of usage. From there you can edit too ... :)

Comment: I know that way, but it doesn't show the result like the result which is generated after choosing 'Analyze->Inspect Code'. I want to know how many in each type of Suppress Warning